# AWS Glue dynamic frame - no column headers if no data

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I read the Glue catalog table, convert it to dataframe & print the schema using the below (spark with Python)

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='database_name',
                                                        table_name='table_name',
                                                        redshift_tmp_dir=args['TempDir'])
df = dyf.toDF()
df.printschema()
```

It works fine when the table has data.
But, It doesn't print the schema if the table is empty (it is unable to get the schema of an empty table). As a result the future joins are failing.
Is there an way to overcome this and make the dynamic frame get the table schema from catalog even for an empty table or any other alternatives?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. It is not ideal but it works. If you call apply_mapping() on your DynamicFrame, it will preserve the schema in the DataFrame. For example, if your table has column `last_name`, you can do:

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database='database_name',
                                                        table_name='table_name',
                                                        
df = dyf.apply_mapping([
  ("last_name", "string", "last_name", "string")
])toDF()
df.printschema()
```